# Group of order $pq$ with $p<q$ prime has $q-1$ elements of order $q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

> If $p<q$ are primes and $G$ is a group of order $pq$, then $G$ has exactly $q-1$ elements of order $q$.

My attempt was:

Use Sylow theorem to show that $G$ has only one subgroup of order $q$, so it's cyclic and then generated by let's call $x$. Now the order of $\langle x\rangle$ is $q$, so it has $q$ elements but the unit is in it and $order(e)=1$ so it has a total of $q-1$ elements, thus G has only $q-1$ elements.

Did i go wrong by assuming $G$ has only that many of elements of order $q$ by looking only at the fact that $p$ and $q$ are primes?

Comment: Is there a missing hypothesis that $q > p$? This isn't true in general if $q \leq p$. E.g. $S_3$ has order $6 = 2\cdot 3$ but has $3$ elements of order $2$.

Comment: I'm sorry,there is ,in fact,such hypothesis,thank you

Comment: OK, then the Sylow argument is fine: if $n_q$ is the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups, then $n_q$ must divide $p$ and $n_q$ must equal $1$ modulo $q$. This forces $n_q = 1$, so there is a unique subgroup $Q$ of order $q$. Since $q$ is prime, this subgroup is cyclic and every nonidentity element of $Q$ generates $Q$, so that gives us at least $q-1$ elements of order $q$. Furthermore, any element of $G$ with order $q$ generates a subgroup of order $q$. As $Q$ is the unique such subgroup, this means that the only elements of order $q$ are the ones in $Q$, so there are exactly $q-1$ such elements.

Comment: So my reasoning is right,but i should have included more details on the proof in order to make it clear?

Comment: Would this apply for a semiring?

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien Your reasoning is OK, but you should explain why every nonidentity element of $\langle x \rangle$ has order $q$. (This follows easily from Lagrange's theorem, and the fact that $q$ is prime.) And you should also explain why $G$ has no other elements of order $q$ besides the ones in $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: If you don't mind you can post the last part as answer so i can vote and close the question,thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments: your idea is fine but you should explain why every nonidentity element of $\langle x \rangle$ has order $q$, and you should also explain why $G$ has no other elements of $q$ besides the ones in $\langle x \rangle$.

Here is an argument which addresses these questions.

First, as you noted, we can use the Sylow theorems to deduce that $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $q$. This is because the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups, call it $n_q$, must divide $p$ and must equal to $1$ modulo $q$. This forces $n_q = 1$.

Let's call the unique $q$-Sylow subgroup $Q$. If $x \in Q$ then the order of $x$ must divide $q$ (Lagrange's theorem). Since $q$ is prime, this means that $x$ has order $1$ or $q$. Therefore every nonidentity element of $Q$ has order $q$. This means that $Q$ contains $q-1$ elements of order $q$.

Can $G$ contain any other elements of order $q$? If $x \in G$ has order $q$, then $\langle x \rangle$ is a subgroup of order $q$. But $Q$ is the unique subgroup of order $q$, so $\langle x \rangle = Q$, and in particular, $x \in Q$, so $x$ is one of the $q-1$ elements we already counted.

We conclude that $G$ has exactly $q-1$ elements of order $q$.